# rxjs pipe to observable does not raise when bind it to the observable reference

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, pipe, angular2-observables

Can someone explain me why does this typescript code work, and - map and tap are raised:

```
var request = this.http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
  .pipe(
    map(x => {
      console.log(map);
      //this will be raised
    }),
    tap((x: any) => {
      console.log(tap);
      //this will be raised
    }
    ));
request.subscribe((x) => alert(x));
```

While in this code:

```
var request = this.http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
request.pipe(
  map(x => {
    console.log(map);
    //this will not be raised
  }),
  tap((x: any) => {
     console.log(tap);
    //this will not be raised
  }
  ));
request.subscribe((x) => alert(x));
```

map and tap are not raised.
Why are they behave differently?

And if this is the expected behavior- What is the right way to separate the request creating, and the pipe to a different location, for example - one method creates the request, second binds it to the pipe, and third raises it by calling the 'subscribe'.
Thanks!

Comment: pipe returns an observable. you dont handle it in the second example

Comment: In the first scenario the `tap` and `map` are piped to the observable that is subscribed. In second scenation `tap` and `map` are piped to the observable that is not assigned back to the variable `request`. Piping operators to observables creates modified observable and does not affect the source observable.

Comment: Observable.pipe() does not modify the existing Observable but creates a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you need something like

```
const request = this.http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");

const piped = request.pipe(
  map(x => {
    console.log(map);
  }),
  tap((x: any) => {
     console.log(tap);
  }
  ));

const subscription = piped.subscribe((x) => alert(x));
```

Note: Avoid `var`, use `const/let` instead, they are block-scoped (which is what you want most of the time) while `var` is not.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it without constants. For example if you want to declare variable, then assign some observable to this variable and then pipe this variable and use it as reference you can do it like this:

```
let action$;
switch(someVar) {
   case case1:
      action$ = someObservable;
      break;
   defualt:
      action$ = someObservable2;
      break;
}
action$ = action$.pipe(someRxjsoperator);
```

In this case you will assign newly create observable by pipe to declared variable.